# den Unterschied (aus)machen

Tags: meaning, verb-choice

Wo ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Phrasen:

> Es macht einen Unterschied.

und

> Es macht einen Unterschied aus.

?

Da meine Frage etwas zu allgemein zu sein scheint, gebe ich noch ein paar Beispiele an (im Internet gefunden):

> Es macht den ganzen Unterschied im Leben aus.
>
> Es macht einen Unterschied, an was man glaubt.
>
> Welchen Unterschied macht es, wenn deine Verlobung ein paar Tage
> später erfolgt?
>
> Das macht auch genau den Unterschied aus zwischen politischem Gerede wie diesem und sich wirklich für die Sache einsetzen, (...)

Comment: Das **aus** macht hier keinen Unterschied.

Comment: Ohne Kontext ist die Frage nicht wirklich zu beantworten, der erste erscheint mir aber unvollständig. Komplett wäre *Es macht einen Unterschied, ob man Vorkenntnisse mitbringt.*.

Comment: @janka Meinst du, dass sich der Satz mit »aus« gut anhört? In meinen Ohren klingt er unnatürlich. Versuch dann mal, beide Sätze mit »großen« zu erweitern, dann wird es noch deutlicher.

Comment: *Es macht einen großen Unterschied aus, ob man nur für eine Sache ist oder sie auch selbst durchzieht.* klingt für mich ganz normal.

Comment: Ja, der zweite Satz hört sich völlig unnatürlich an, zumindest für sich allein genommen.

Comment: @Janke: Für mich klingt _"Es macht einen großen Unterschied aus"_ allein schon deshalb nicht normal, weil _es_ nichts ausmachen kann, zumindest wenn _ausmachen_ im Sinne von _feststellen_ oder _erkennen_ gemeint ist. Nach meinem Dafürhalten geht _"Ich kann keinen großen Unterschied ausmachen"_ aber _"Es macht keinen großen Unterschied"_.

Answer (score 1):

> Es macht einen Unterschied, ob x oder y

halte ich für einen Anglizismus, der aus der direkten Übersetzung von "makes a difference" entstanden ist, genau wie "makes sense" zu "macht einen Sinn" geworden ist. Das "Duden-Universallexikon" gibt mir dabei recht und nennt es einen "eingebürgerten Anglizismus".

> Ich mache einen Unterschied zwischen Leuten, die eine Meinung haben, und welchen, die sie nur verbreiten

(Im Sinne von "ich differenziere zwischen x und y") Ist für mich eine eher klassische deutsche Verwendung, denn diese Form gibt es im Englischen so nicht.

Die Form deiner beiden Beispiele ist für mich eher

> Der Unterschied zwischen x und y ist ...

oder

> Der Hauptunterschied zwischen x und y besteht in ...

(weil: Der Unterschied ist ja schon da, den muss man in diesem Fall nicht erst machen)

Sieht man vom Anglizismus ab: Vom Sinn her sind deine beiden Beispiele deckungsgleich. Ohne weiteren Kontext sehe ich keinen Unterschied.

Comment: Aber die Wörter »machen« und »ausmachen« sind unterschiedlich. »Einen U. machen« ist, wie du sagst, ein Anglizismus. »Einen U. ausmachen« bedeutet etwas anderes, nämlich »einen U. erkennen«. Z. B.: »Ich mache einen Unterschied in der Farbigkeit aus.« Ich vermute, die Ähnlichkeit der Ausdrücke führt zu der häufigen Vereinheitlichung.

Comment: Oder Bedeutung Nummer 3 von »ausmachen« im dwds: bilden, darstellen. »Moderne Bauten machen die neue Stadt aus.« In diesem Sinne passt das Bsp. in der Frage jedoch nicht.

Comment: @Philipp Bedeutung 3 kann nur funktionieren, wenn "es" selbst den Unterschied darstellt, etwa so wie in dem Satz _"Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Säcken Kartoffeln macht zwei Kilogramm aus."_ Das abstrakte "es" ist aber kein Unterschied an sich, weshalb _Es macht keinen Unterschied aus_ nicht im Sinne von Bedeutung 3 funktionieren kann.

Comment: @björnfriedrich Das stimmt, und mit dem zweiten Kommentar wollte ich diese Einsicht deutlich machen